# What is the mechanism behind auto-generated "This does not provide an answer to the question" comments?

Tags: discussion, review, low-quality-posts, automatic-comments

Twice today I have received the following identical comment to an answer of mine:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

The comments in question:

- [compile issue using C99 does it to have a scope around each if?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23106389/compile-issue-using-c99-does-it-to-have-a-scope-around-each-if/23107275#comment35331152_23107275)
- [Proper way to handle enum with associated strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23104482/proper-way-to-handle-enum-with-associated-strings/23104594#comment35318702_23104594)

Note that I have edited both of my answers since the comments to my answers were posted.

I've not noticed this before. Is there something new? What is the mechanism? I guess that the comments are being auto-generated as a result of a not-an-answer flag. Is that correct?

FWIW, in neither case was I critiquing or requesting clarification from an author. The comments in both cases struck me as a little odd.

Comment: Most of these comments can be flagged, really. They're not often used correctly. It's just one of the many silly little things robo-reviewers do, I reckon.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Should those flags go to a Review Queue review queue?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a drawback with these canned comments being used.  They get applied incorrectly by users going through the review queue.  Be glad you didn't get multiple versions of this comment by several users.

Comment: @Servy: The Low Quality Posts Review Queue review queue, to be exact.

Comment: Is this new or was I just unlucky in getting my first two on the same day?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Well, I was hoping for it to be able to review other queues as well. ;)

Comment: @Servy: Yeah, but we do need every review queue to have its own queue - after all, one can never have enough review badges.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It's over a year old.

Comment: You might be seeing more of this now that "not an answer" flags are feeding answers into the Low Quality review queue (both of these answers were flagged, which is what brought them into the queue), rather than being exposed to moderators. With how easy it is to leave automated comments within the review system, many short answers have been accumulating a few of these comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are automated comments generated from a specific action taken in the Very Low Quality review queue.